# Is there a difference if I added the window handle or NULL value

Tags: windows, winapi, null, handle

I have a little problem.
I will show you an example firstly, then I will tell you what the problem.

**Example:**

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
   TranslateMessage(&msg);
   DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

That example work correctly, but if the parameter 2 in "GetMessage" function changed to a handle name of window as the following:

**Example2: after changed**

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, Hwnd, 0, 0)){
   TranslateMessage(&msg);
   DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Will occurs a little problem when exit the program.
still the program works in processes list.
And need to select it then click on end process button to terminate the program

And now, Is there a difference between add (NULL or window handle)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you encounter in your second example is that after your window is destroyed,  the window handle you supply to `GetMessage()` is no longer valid.  Every subsequent call returns an error to notify you of that (with `GetLastError()` giving `ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE`), but the code doesn’t handle this case and so ends up in a busy loop forever.

This is why [the MSDN Library page for `GetMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms644936.aspx) advises against using `while (GetMessage(...))`.

Comment: is there any solution to make the second example works fine, and make the program ends correctly. Note that I have one window .

Comment: @LionKing: Yes, Don't needlessly specify a window handle.

Comment: @Lion King: There are lots of ways of doing it, but all more complicated than using a `NULL` window handle with `GetMessage()`.  What are your reasons for preferring the second approach over the first?

Comment: No reason, Can I use it always with NULL if I have one window  or more?

Comment: @Lion King: In general, yes: you can always use `NULL` to keep your message loop as simple as possible, however many windows you’ve got. `DispatchMessage()` makes sure that each message ends up in the right place.

Comment: @Brian Nixon: Thank you for continued help

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental difference between the two examples you presented is how the messages are handled by your application. The first example will pull messages from the message queue for any of the windows you may create within the application. The later example will pull message only from the window associated with the handle that is passed to the function. You could potentially create many windows within your application. If you were only interested in capturing messages for a particular window, that parameter will serve to limit the messages that are translated and dispatched to the window procedure function. However, if you plan to create only a single window, the difference is negligible.

Comment: I have indeed one window, I want to know how the difference is negligible, and the program works fine with first example and the second example doesn't works fine. although in the second example I have specified the handle of window

Comment: If an application creates a single window, the GetMessage() function will have no need to delegate messages to a particular window because all messages will be in the context of that single window. However, should you choose to pass the window handle to the function, there should be no adverse differences. Without any additional information, I could only assume that your window procedure function isn't handling the window messages effectively.